# Vue CLI 4 - Vuetfiy, Conflict between scss variable

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

After installing Vuetify, I have a problem with some of my scss variables. Using scss variables like $red, $blue, $pink,.... VueJS returns an error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/map/GmapAutocompleteField.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss& (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/vuetify-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/map/GmapAutocompleteField.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: ("base": #F44336, "lighten-5": #FFEBEE, "lighten-4": #FFCDD2, "lighten-3": #EF9A9A, "lighten-2": #E57373, "lighten-1": #EF5350, "darken-1": #E53935, "darken-2": #D32F2F, "darken-3": #C62828, "darken-4": #B71C1C, "accent-1": #FF8A80, "accent-2": #FF5252, "accent-3": #FF1744, "accent-4": #D50000, #e2001a: null) isn't a valid CSS value.
   ╷
46 │       background-color: $red;
   │                         ^^^^
   ╵
```

I share my variable between my components with vue.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: "/",
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true
  },
  pwa: pwaArgs,
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        prependData: `@import "~@/scss/_variables.scss";`
      }
    }
  }
};
```

But if i change my variable name to $red-color everything work.

Any idea how to avoid this conflict ?